# Alternatives to "Extending" Java Enums

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

I'm doing a very dumbed down ALife-esque application, and I which to have the following classes with the following inheritance relationship:

(Abstract)Lifeform <-- Plant

(Abstract)Lifeform <-- Animal

Plants and Animals share some states, and I'd ideally like this behavior to live in rudamentary form within Lifeform.

```
abstract class Lifeform
{
    public static enum State
    {
        IDLE,
        DEAD
    }

    protected void someMethodSomewhere()
    {
        ....
        state = State.IDLE;   // this to be recognized by inherited creatures
        ....
    }
    protected State state;
}

class Plant extends Lifeform
{
    public Plant() { state=new Plant.State(); }

    public static enum State extends Lifeform.State  // (can't)
    {
        FEEDING,
        REPRODUCING,
    }
}

class Animal extends Lifeform
{
    public Animal() { state=new Animal.State(); }

    public static enum State extends Lifeform.State  // (can't)
    {
        FEEDING,
        FORAGING,
        FLEEING,
        GROUPING,
        REPRODUCING
    }

    // elsewhere in some method
    public void someMethod()
    {
        switch(state)
        {
            case IDLE: (...)     // from Lifeform.State
            case FEEDING: (...)  // from Animal.State
            case DEAD: (...)
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a facility in the later (1.5+) java's that allow for something similar to this, or am I best off embedding this state hierarchy within it's own traditional class?

Comment: You could have all the states in a single `enum` and validate the exact state for the class. Or you can just have separate `enum`s.

Comment: @Luiggi, The first solution I rejected early on because it involves having a base class maintain information about all potential subclasses.  A rudamentary lifeform shouldn't have to do this.  The second keeps the Lifeform class from changing the state as necessary.

Comment: @Luiggi, that solution you posted as "already answered" doesn't come up with a clean example.  It also doesn't address the cleanliness of switch()/case.

Comment: Well, in Java you cannot extend from an `enum`, so your use case is just impossible as is. There are two alternatives, probably you should not use an `enum` to solve this *issue*.

Comment: You can have enums implement interfaces if you want to, assuming the enums need to have specific methods.  But what you are doing isn't an option.

Comment: @Luiggi, yes, and that's the initial premise I'm starting with---that enum's by themselves can't solve this.  What I'm not clear on the cleanest route to take here.  States need to live at each level.  I wish to maintain the hierarchy of the creatures (instead of one lifeform that can simply evolve by itself into anything and still maintain its own class), and I wish no particular level to have insight into sub levels, which frankly, would be gross.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I don't think this is an enum problem as much as it is a state machine problem.

You have the name `State` which to me implies that you are actually working with a state machine. I would not use `enum` for this and actually model a proper state machine.

From the *states* that you have posted in your question, they imply a finite state machine as well. I think you are just going to implement some sort of state machine around these `enums` as an end result and should just go ahead and start where you are going to end up eventually.

I have used [state machine compiler](http://smc.sourceforge.net/) to great effect in the past to make creating and managing the state transitions simply.

[Ragel](http://www.colm.net/open-source/ragel/) looks like a good solution as well.

#### The only way you can do what you want is to roll your own pre-1.4 TypeSafe Enum

Before Java had `enum` as a type, I used a [`Type Safe Enum Pattern`](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/enum.html) template in my IDE to create what was actually a richer implementation of what ended up in the language.

It is essentially just a Java class with `final` instance members and a `private` constructor and `public final static` instances of itself.

*I will still warn that extending `enum` is not allowed for a very good reason and trying to work around it will probably give you more grief than it will solve.*

Comment: Could well be.  However the exercise for me is in building such a state machine by hand, and this is only an example.  I've built my own SM and it functions as I expect it to.  However, I'm trying to build functionality within various levels that are inherited via a Genome, and this involves having superclasses manage the states that they themselves understand.  Consider the following arrangement that I didn't put into the question (on purpose):

(Abstract)Lifeform <-- (Abstract)Animal <-- Herbavore, and 
(Abstract)Lifeform <-- (Abstract)Animal <-- Predator.

Lots of commonality in Animal.

Comment: yes, in fact that's the same solution I've been using since 1997.  It sounds though from your caveat that I'm heading in the wrong direction if I intend on using anything enum like in an inherited fashion.  Not sure on a clean solution then because I do want the abstract superclasses ("supercreatures" I suppose) to be cognizant of and modify states, if only by a default set of protected methods that may or may not be overridden later.

Comment: **BTW**, did you happen to see this beastie: javax.print.attribute.EnumSyntax?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I've used for years, in case it helps someone.  I've rewritten it somewhat.

Note: It purposefully does not implement value support.  This is not a difficult change, and frankly, I don't use them, so I pulled it out.  I also rewrote it from my originally ancient version.

Note: I'm primarily supplying it here because it contains toString() support to yield the field name (no matter what you've used) from any subclass.

I've also specified field errors due to access restrictions to be a catastrophic (execution ending) error.  You can modify this to be any exception handling you choose, but I would suggest you leave it as is.

```
package tgm.utils;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;


public abstract class InheritableEnum
{
    protected InheritableEnum() {}

    public String toString()
    {
        String returnStr = "Unknown InheritableEnum["+super.toString()+"]";

        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getFields();        
        for (Field f : fields)
        {
            try
            {
                if (f.get(this) == this)
                {
                    returnStr = f.getName();
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch(IllegalAccessException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Illegal access on field["+f+"]");
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }

        return returnStr;
    }
}
```

Then you would use it similarly:

```
public class State extends InheritableEnum
{
    public static final State DEAD    = new State();
    public static final State EATING  = new State();
    public static final State GROWING = new State();
}
```